# socket can t connect to localhost

Tags: sockets, localhost

I write this code under windows 8.1. I want to connect my socket to the localhost at first. then connect to a virtual machine I created and that is connected to the local networks. 
Here is my code.

```
//Create my socket

SOCKET sock;
SOCKADDR_IN sin;
sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
sin.sin_family      = AF_INET;
sin.sin_port        = htons(22);
sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
bind(sock, (SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin));

if(connect(sock ,(SOCKADDR *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) <0) 
{
    printf("socket can't connect to the server 192.168.56.101 \n");
}
else
{
    printf("socket succeeded to connect to the server 192.168.56.101 \n");
}
```

Comment: Print the *error,* with `perror()`, not just some random message of your own devising.

Comment: It gives me : No error

Comment: *What* gives you 'no error'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks strange and it is not clear what it should do. If you want to establish connection then you need *two sockets* and they are typically in different processes. The server process normally calls

```
socket()   // create a socket
bind()     // bind socket to local address and port
listen()   // start listening
accept()   // wait for connection from client and return connected socket
           // communication over the socket
close()
```

whereas the client usually calls

```
socket()
connect()    // connect to the server
             // communication over the socket
close()
```

The client may optionally call `bind()` if it wants specify outgoing port but it is usually not necessary because OS assigns an ephemeral port automatically.

The code above calls `bind()` and then `connect()` to the same address. If the `bind()` is successful then nothing is listening on this address and the `connect()` obviously fails.